# Get data from prometheus only from last scrape iteration

Tags: prometheus

**Use case**

I am creating a tool to show the resource requests of all pods in a kubernetes cluster. Prometheus already scrapes my prometheus metric exporter and historically saves all the scraped metrics (interval 10s), so that I could even see the resource requests from all pods 10 days ago.

**The problem**

Every time a pod has been redeployed it does change the name. However I only want to show the resource requests of actually RUNNING pods. For this purpose I could obviously add a time selector like, show me only max 15s old results, but that would be a little hack. If possible I'd like to get the results from the latest scrape iteration (which in case of problems could be older than 15s).

**The question**

What's the best way to get only those prometheus metrics which have been scraped in the last iteration?

`eagle_container_resource_requests_cpu` for instance would return the requested CPU cores of pods which nowadays no longer exist.

**Side note:** I am trying to achieve this behaviour in a Grafana table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staleness might be what you are looking for: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness

So after 5 minutes you should begin to see values disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

When you query your metric `eagle_container_resource_requests_cpu` you get the latest value, e.g. this is an actual request you send by using Prometheus graph execution:

```
https://<prometheus-url>/api/v1/query?query=eagle_container_resource_requests_cpu&time=1541769935.01&_=1541769677378
```

More over, you can verify it with directly calling [Prometheus API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries):

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=eagle_container_resource_requests_cpu&time=2018-11-09T10:10:51.781Z'
```

Both responses will contain the time stamp metric was scraped, e.g.:

`"value":[1541770056.042,"11"]`

If you would like to see this in Grafana's singlestat chart:

You can either see the "current" (the latest) value, or time of this last point.

[image]

Comment: Hm unfortunately that doesn't help me as I am using grafana to show these metrics. I don't see how i could tell it to only consider values with the most recent scrape timtestamp?

Comment: @kentor Please see my last edit, in which I added a screenshot how to see the latest scraped value in Grafana.

Comment: As I am using a table I don't have such an option. I couldn't find it somewhere else when I use a table.